# Portfolio & Blog cohabitation : multiple single.php files?

Tags: blog, customization, single

I'm currently creating a website that's going to be powered by Wordpress and have both a portfolio and a blog.

How should I go about coding up the `single.php`?

I understand custom post types are the way to go when it comes to a portfolio+blog setup, but when it comes to displaying the post/portfolio item in its entirety, is there such a thing as multiple `single.php` files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) page. Custom post types will use `single-{post_type}.php` template if it exists.

Comment: Thank you, I came across this page before but wasn't sure whether this was what I wanted. I'll go ahead and educate myself on the subject.